# Vim + Airline + Linux sloppy exit

Tags: linux, vim, pathogen

I have prepared a small video by recording my desktop to show you what happens. The steps that happen are (beforehand, note that `execute pathogen#infect()` is **enabled** in my *.vimrc*):

1. `vim`
2. `:q` *
3. `vim ~/.vimrc` and comment out *`execute pathogen#infect()`*
4. `clear`
5. `vim`
6. `:q` **

* Here, you can see that when I quit, the cursor is suddenly at the bottom and there is still a strip of the background left on the last line.

** Here, you can see that after quitting vim, the cursor is where it was before vim started and everything looks normal.

link to video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zeb1BzcTwmk&feature=youtu.be

My questions are how can I fix this, and where should I report this?

So, it turns out that it is `airline` and not pathogen (when I remove the `airline` bundle, everything works fine). Is airline solely built for Mac?

Comment: Airline and Solarized are both piles of crap. I have no idea why so many people keep using them despite all the problems they cause and their general lack of usefulness. Also, you should post your finding as an answer.

Comment: @romainl I'm not the biggest fan of airline, but it does look kinda cool - especially on mac (in linux... eh). I think solarized is ok, though. It's not really a pile of crap. Perhaps it is over-documented, but that is about it. I will submit an answer. Lastly, "That's like your opinion, man." - the Dude

Comment: If that was only an opinion I would keep it for me but it's not. In the few years I've spent here and in other Vim communities, the number of *line and Solarized issues I've seen has been staggering. Powerline, Airline and Solarized are all extremely over-engineered and very poorly designed.

Comment: @dylnmc that's not an answer but you might be interested in the [stackexchange site dedicated to vim](http://vi.stackexchange.com/) for a future question about this editor ;)

Answer (score 0):

Despite my initial belief that it was `pathogen` causing the error (since when I commented out `pathogen`, everything became normal), I eventually found that the cause is `airline`. I guess it just doesn't work in Linux (running mint 17.1 or something like that... rebecca).

My original video, nonetheless, documents the problem (the first time I quit and when I quit from `.vimrc`, you can see the background lingering).